# Most efficient data storage

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, storage

I need to transform/convert/process [TransXchange](http://www.131500.com.au/transport-data-exchange-program/nsw-public-transport-data-exchange-tdx-program) data dump to reduce the size of data as some of the xml files can be up to 400 MB. I have the following options:

- Sqlite database
- CSV files
- Binary Serialization
- ?

What is the best method of reducing the file sizes so that they would be feasible for use in a Windows Phone 7 application?

EDIT: I am going to create journey planning application that will allow users to specify source and destination. The application will then present the available services. In down under we have spotty mobile broadband coverage therefore I am aiming to have offline application.

Comment: Will the application actually require access to all the data all the time? If not, it would be better if a web service could treat the raw data as required and then send to the WP7 client only what's strictly necessary.

Comment: Using something like Zip compression on a 400MB XML file would be bad - as you'd have to decompress the entire file in order to read it. Using some custom binary compression might work - but then you might as well store in binary...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This analysis is superb for showing you the timing of serialisation: http://www.eugenedotnet.com/2010/12/windows-phone-7-serialization-comparison/

For size... It's quite easy to guess that binary is smaller than sqlite (or Sterling) which in turn is smaller than CSV

However, if you are looking at processing 400MB of data on the phone... then I'd say you are doing the wrong thing - farm the processing out to a server (to the cloud?) and just view the summary results on the phone - think "thin client".

(Off to wash my mouth out now after all those jargon words!)

Comment: Thanks for link to great comparison. I suspected binary serialization would be most size efficient but I didn't think it would be the quickest.

Comment: If you are intending to store this much data on your phone, then you will want to consider quick random access to that data as well as efficient compression size. For this reason, I'd take a look at using a database like Sterling or at using some kind of custom fixed size binary records with some kind of indexing.

Answer (score 2):

The main question is what are you going to do with that data.

If you just need to store the data and files are fine then binary serialization + compression (zlib, lzo...) will work best.

CSV won't do you any good.. will probably occupy more than the XML.

Database (for example, Sqlite) is the most expensive it terms of storage but you can manage and search the data more easily.

Comment: I disagree - database should take up less than CSV or XML - as it should store in binary (but I do agree it depends how well the DB is written and configured)

Comment: Also I disagree that CSV will take up more than XML - generally XML is very bloated as it has all those Tags - e.g. a single number might be stored as <DoubleValue>12.2313452<DoubleValue>

Comment: Yeah, not quite seeing how CSV would take more space than XML o.O